# What is the 'illuminating lamp' mentioned in Surah Al-Ahzab?

Tags: quran, tafseer

What is the 'illuminating lamp' mentioned in [Surah Al-Ahzab](https://quran.com/33)(The Clans)?

> O Prophet, indeed We have sent you as a witness and a bringer of good tidings and a warner.([33:45](https://quran.com/33))
>
> And one who invites to Allah, by His permission, and an illuminating lamp. ([33:46](https://quran.com/33))

Is it the Quran?

Comment: Doesn't that just refer to Muhammad himself? The English translation, at least, seems to read pretty clearly that he's [a witness] and [a bringer of good tidings] and [a warner] and [one who invites to Allah] and [an illuminating lamp].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prophet Muhammad ﷺ is being referred to as that lamp (*Siraajan-Muneeraa*).

Imam At-Tabari says in his [Tafseer of Al-Ahzaab:46](http://altafasir.com/al-quran/surat/33/al-ahzab/46/al-tabari):

> { وَسِرَاجاً مُنِـيراً } يقول: وضياء لـخـلقه يستضيء بـالنور الذي أتـيتهم به من عند الله عبـاده
>   { مُنِـيراً } يقول: ضياء ينـير لـمن استضاء بضوئه، وعمل بـما أمره. وإنـما يعنـي بذلك، أنه يهدي به من اتبعه من أمته.
>
> [Qatadah] said (about *Siraajan-Muneeraa*):
>   And he is a light for Allah's creation, illuminating with the light which [Prophet Muhammad] has come with from Allah to His servants
>
> And he said (about *Muneeraa*):
>   A lamp that illuminates those who seek to be enlightened by its light, and perform what they have been commanded to do.
>
> **And what is meant by that is that he guides whoever follows him from his *Ummah*.**

---

And [Ibn Al-Jawzi](http://altafasir.com/al-quran/surat/33/al-ahzab/46/ibn-al-jawzi) says something similar:

> { وسراجاً منيراً } أي: أنت لِمَن اتَّبعك { سراجاً } ، أي: كالسِّراج المضيء في الظلمة يُهتدى به.
>
> It means that you (i.e. Muhammad) are a lamp for those who follow you; in other words like a lamp that acts as a guiding light in the darkness.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Ibn Katheer](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1841&Itemid=89),

> *and as a lamp spreading light*
>
> means, `the Message that you bring is as
>    clear as the sun shining brightly, and no one can deny it except those
>    who are stubborn.'

Answer (score 5):

Well, it seems like the verse illuminating lamp is a word by word translation to English. It also seems to refer to the Prophet.

In arabic that is more a metaphor, as explained in the tafsirs:

**[Tabari](http://altafasir.com/al-quran/surat/33/al-ahzab/46/al-tabari):**

> يقول: ضياء ينـير لـمن استضاء بضوئه، وعمل بـما أمره. **وإنـما يعنـي بذلك، أنه يهدي به من اتبعه من أمته**
>   The meaning of that is that he guides with it (his light) the one who follows him.

[Razi](http://altafasir.com/al-quran/surat/33/al-ahzab/46/razi):

> أي مبرهناً على ما يقول مظهراً له بأوضح الحجج

[Qurtubi](http://altafasir.com/al-quran/surat/33/al-ahzab/46/al-qurtubi) (in arabic) also adds some more explanation about the term.

Comment: Interesting how we thought of selecting the same Tafseer and highlighting the same part of it